# Convert excel formula to human readable formulas - macOS

Tags: macos, math, microsoft-word

Is there any free software which can convert excel formulas to human readable format as shown below? (for macOS)

[image]

**Reason:** I'm fed up of writing long formulas one character at a time in the `microsoft word`, so I either need some software which I can convert excel formulas to human readable format.
The software can be producing an image, so I can paste the image to `ms word`, or `ms word` compatible format so I can copy and paste the text formula.